# Is there a difference between Rust's `macro_rules!` and Scheme's `syntax-rules`?

Tags: rust, lisp, meta-programming, scheme

This is an example for the use of Rust's `macro_rules!`:

```rust
macro_rules! add {
    ($a:expr,$b:expr) => {{
        $a + $b
    }};
    ($a:expr) => {{
        $a
    }};
}
```

A similar example for Scheme using `syntax-rules` could be:

```scheme
(define-syntax add
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a b) (+ a b))
    ((_ a)   a)))
```

One might think that this two language features are equivalent.  But is it the case or is there a hidden difference?

Answer (score 15):

[Rust's macros are directly inspired by Scheme's macros](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/azlqnj/prior_art_for_rusts_macros/ei8tf2a/), but they aren't the same.

First, I should clarify that while there is a formal specification to Scheme (R*n*RS), there are many more commonly used extended dialects, and each have their own `syntax-rules` implementations which are slightly different. Here I cite [R6RS](https://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html#node_chap_12), [Chez Scheme](https://www.scheme.com/csug8/syntax.html), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Syntax-Rules.html) and [Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-rules%29%29). I believe all the similarities and differences listed apply between Rust and any of the Scheme dialects.

### Similarities

- All have **function-like syntax**, but unlike functions, are evaluated at compile-time.
- All do a sort of **pattern-match on the AST** provided and produce a new AST.
- All can have **multiple cases**, which are tried top-to-bottom.
- All have some form of **hygiene**, which prevents identifiers inside the macro from mixing with identifiers with the same name outside of the macro ([Rust](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-hygiene.html), [R6RS](https://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_12.1), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Syntax-Rules.html#Hygiene), [Racket](https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/hygiene.html)).
- All allow **recursive macros** (macros whose expansion calls themselves again) and **nested macros** (macros whose expansion defines other macros). For nested macros, there are ways to get [the `$` in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53971532) and [`...` in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68743610) within the inner macros working correctly.
- All have a long list of "tricks" to create complicated macros (examples in [Rust](https://blog.cloudflare.com/writing-complex-macros-in-rust-reverse-polish-notation/), [2](https://cohost.org/poliorcetics/post/363003-a-rust-macro-trick-i), [Scheme](https://github.com/mnieper/scheme-macros), [2](https://okmij.org/ftp/Scheme/macros.html), [3](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Ejavaplt/311/Readings/macroslides.pdf); just Google "Rust macro tricks" and "Scheme macro tricks" for more examples).

### Differences

- **Rust macros may match syntax elements of particular types (e.g. `expr`)**. These syntax elements may actually consist of multiple syntax-nodes and require further parsing before they get matched (very complicated). `syntax-rules` only matches individual nodes (equivalent to `tt`), and matching is done after all parsing (very simple).
- **Rust has "optional fragments"** (`$(...)?`) which match zero-or-one repetition of a sequence of syntax-nodes, and `$(...)+` fragments which match one-or-many. Scheme only has `...` which matches zero-or-many repetitions of a syntax-node.

  - Related, **Rust's repetitions can contain multiple syntax-nodes** (which are matched in repeating sequence, e.g. `$(a b)*` matches `a b a b a b`), Scheme's repetitions only contain one.
  - Scheme patterns may also have a dotted-pair, which matches the remaining elements of a Scheme "list" including the dotted-pair if it ends in one. Rust has no analogue to dotted-pairs.
- Rust has a large set of [ambiguity rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macro-ambiguity.html) due to its complicated macro parsing and forwards-compatibility with new syntax. **Scheme has no ambiguity rules, because there's no ambiguity to how the macro pattern is matched**, and Scheme's syntax will never change to introduce one.
- Macros in Rust can only be local to a module, unless you use [macros 2.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39412) which is experimental and requires nightly Rust. **Scheme has `let-syntax` which creates its own local scope and defines macros which only apply to that scope** (e.g. `(let-syntax ([f (syntax-rules () [(_ x) x])]) (f 1))`).
- This is technically off-topic because it goes beyond `syntax-rules` and `macro_rules!`, but **the way that Rust and Scheme let you write more complicated macros are completely different**.

  - Rust's `macro_rules!` (AKA "Macro By Example") is very limited. If you want to "pull back the curtain" and manipulate syntax programmatically within the Rust language, you must use [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html). These must be defined in a separate `proc-macro` crate which the code which uses the macros must depend on. Moreover, proc-macros abandon Rust's powerful syntax pattern-matching and give you the raw stream of tokens to manipulate directly.
  - In contrast, **Scheme has [`syntax-case`](https://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html) which is what `syntax-rules` expands to**. `syntax-case` still lets you pattern-match syntax, but instead of the RHS being the result AST, **`syntax-case` contains arbitrary Scheme code which gets evaluated and produces a ["syntax object"](https://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_12.2)** like `#'(foo (bar . baz))`. **Macros defined with `define-syntax`/`let-syntax` and `syntax-case` can be used within the same file**, and Racket in particular even lets you define macros for other macros within the same file using statements like [`begin-for-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._begin-for-syntax%29%29) (see [phase levels](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/phases.html))

### [`syntax/parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html): the real origin of Rust-style macros

Racket in particular has a newer macro system, `syntax/parse`, which is what specifically inspired Rust's macros. [`define-syntax-parse-rule`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Defining_Simple_Macros.html) is the analogue to Rust's `macro_rules!`.

Like `macro_rules!`, `syntax/parse` can match different kinds of syntax using `:expr`, `:id`, etc. (called [syntax classes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Library_Syntax_Classes_and_Literal_Sets.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._expr%29%29), although in Rust they're called [designators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros/designators.html)). `syntax/parse` can also match repeating sequences of nodes using [the `~seq` syntax pattern](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._%7E7eseq%29%29).

But `syntax/parse` is much more expressive than `macro_rules!`. You can [define your own syntax classes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-specifying.html), and there are other [syntax patterns](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html); e.g. [`~or`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28elem._%28pattern-link._%28%7E7eor%2A._s%29%29%29) lets you match local alternatives (e.g. `(number (~or 1 2 3))` matches `(number 1)` and `(number 3)`), and [`~not`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._%7E7enot%29%29) creates a macro which matches any syntax node *except* ones which match its argument. Moreover, `syntax/parse` provides [`syntax-parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Parsing_Syntax.html), the analogue to `syntax-case`, which lets you evaluate arbitrary Racket code when producing the result syntax.

---

### Main references

- [Rust `macro_rules!` "Macros by Example"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html)
- [R6RS `syntax-case`](https://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html) (which `syntax-rules` expands to)
- [Chez Scheme macros](https://www.scheme.com/csug8/syntax.html)
- [Guile Scheme `syntax-rules`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Syntax-Rules.html)
- [Racket scheme pattern-based macros](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html), [`syntax-rules`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-rules%29%29) and [the full "Macros" reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Macros.html)
- [Reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html) and [paper](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/icfp10-cf.pdf) of Racket's `syntax/parse`

Comment: Scheme requires additional parenthesis: `(a b) ...` instead of `$(a b)*`.

Comment: The difference is that `(a b)` is one syntax node. In Scheme you can't match repetitions without the parenthesis (e.g. `a b a b a b`) without using `syntax-case` and manually checking, you can only match something like `(a b) (a b) (a b)`

Comment: A crucial missing citation here is [`syntax-parse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html), which was presented in the paper [Fortifying Macros](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/icfp10-cf.pdf). `syntax-parse` is a descendant of `syntax-case` that supports both repetitions without parentheses and matching syntax elements of particular types (and even uses the same colon syntax for the latter). It was a direct inspiration for those aspects of the Rust macro system.

Comment: Thanks, I added it as a new section